# Estimating Cassandra KeyCache

Tags: cassandra

We are currently in the process of deploying a larger Cassandra cluster and looking for ways to estimate the best size of the key cache. Or more accurately looking for a way of finding out the size of one row in the key cache.

I have tried tying into the integrated metrics systems using graphite, but I wasn't able to receive any clear answer. Further I tried putting my own debugging code into org.cassandra.io.sstable, but this neither yielded any concrete results.

We are using Cassandra 1.20.10, but are there any fool proof solutions to getting the size of one row in the key cache?

With best regards,

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [jamm](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm). Its a library used for measuring the size of an object in memory.

You need to add `-javaagent:"/path/to/jamm.jar"` to your startup parameters but *cassandra is configured to start with jamm, so if you change internal cassandra code, this is already done for you.*

To size of objects (in bytes):

```
MemoryMeter meter = new MemoryMeter();
meter.measureDeep(object);
```

Measure deep is a more costly but much more accurate measurement of an object's memory size.

Answer (score 0):

For estimation of key size, let's assume you intended to store 1 million keys in cache, each key of length 60 bytes on an average.  There will be some overhead to store the key, lets say it is 40 bytes that means key size per row = 100 bytes.

Since we need to cache 1 million keys

total key cache = 1 mn * 100 = 100 Mbytes

perform this for each CF in your keyspace.